# Select all links that have a certain get param?

Tags: jquery

For example, I want to match all links that have the `iframe` param. Thus, it would match:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com?iframe">
<a href="http://www.example.com?iframe=1">
<a href="http://www.example.com?iframe&sortby=awesomeness">
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use an [attribute-contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), like this:

```
$("a[href*='?iframe'], a[href*='&iframe']")
```

This would also find things like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com?sortby=awesomeness&iframe">
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use jQuery it would be

```
var iframeLinks = $("a[href*='iframe']")
```

Comment: Keep in mind this would also find it *anywhere* in the link, e.g. `www.iframe.com` would also match :)

Answer (score 0):

if the search is very specific, you can create a new selector:

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.tagName = function() {
    return this.get(0).tagName.toLowerCase();
  }

  $.expr[':'].inHRef = function(obj, index, meta, stack){

    if ($(obj).tagName() != 'a')
      return false;

    var afi = $(obj).attr('href').split('?'), sfi, txt = meta[3];

    if (afi.length == 1)
       return false;

    sfi = afi[1];

    // Regular Expression

    var rgCI = '\\'+sfi+'\\gi';

    // case-insensitive
    return (rgCI.match(txt));

    var rgCS = '\\'+sfi+'\\g';

    // case-sensitive
    //return (rgCS.match(txt));

    // IndexOf

    // case-insensitive
    //return ( sfi.toLowerCase().indexOf(txt.toLowerCase()) > -1);

    // case-sensitive
    //return ( sfi.indexOf(txt) > -1);

};

})(jQuery);

$(function() {

    $('a:inHRef(iframe)').css('background-color', '#aaaaa0');

});​
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/qzpbd/)

[example update](http://jsfiddle.net/qzpbd/1/)

[example end update](http://jsfiddle.net/qzpbd/4/)

Comment: This would also have the same contains issues :) http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/qzpbd/3/